# htaccess Works On Local Server And Dev, Not Working on Godaddy Server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the following .htaccess file in my local and development servers, however when I deploy this .htaccess file to my godaddy prod server, I get a 500 error. However if I browse to http://example.com/bootstrap.php I get a 404 resource not available at /

my directory structure is this:

```
+ folder
+--folder of errord domain

# this funnels every request through the bootstrap unless the request includes a specific file or document
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(js|css|errors|images|fonts|media)
  RewriteRule !.(js|css|ico|gif|jpg|png|swf|ttf|eot|svg|woff|GIF|pdf)$ bootstrap.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^.*$ bootstrap.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Every environment is different. Contact GoDaddy support.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101600/htaccess-not-working-on-godaddy

Comment: godaddy support has no idea of what i am referring to, have alreaady called them.